# django: how to read and manipulate .csv file from View.py

Tags: python, django, pandas, csv

I am trying to work from csv files located inside of a django app. I am trying to load the file using pandas like: `pd.read_csv("...")` without success, I keep getting an error.

Here is what the directory tree looks like:

```
├── __pycache__
│   ├── forms.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── urls.cpython-36.pyc
├── apps.py
├── files
│   ├── t1.csv
│   ├── t2.csv
│   ├── t3.csv
│   ├── t4.csv
│   └── parametre.csv
├── finished_apps.py
├── forms.py
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── 0002_remove_carriers_carriersheet.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── 0003_auto_20211021_1200.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── 0004_auto_20211021_1203.cpython-36.pyc
│       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
├── models.py
├── views.py
├── templates
│   ├── add_carrier.html
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── delete_carrier.html
│   ├── delete_carrier_confirmation.html
│   ├── _carrierdetails.html
│   ├── _carrierlist.html
│   ├── simulation.html
│   └── update_carrier.html
└── urls.py
```

I have tried the following inside of views.py

```
df = pd.read_csv("/files/t1.csv") #not working
df = pd.read_csv("./files/t1.csv") #not working
df = pd.read_csv("t1.csv") #not working
df = pd.read_csv("../files/t1.csv") #not working
```

I have also tried doing that:

```
from files import t1
```

the errors that I am getting are as such:

```
No such file or directory (/file/t1.csv) #for example
```

```
cannot import name 't1'
```

that's not working either.

I am now wondering whether is it possible to import a file this way or I am missing something obvious here!

Comment: Can you provide the error that you get?

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv("carrier/files/t1.csv")` if `carrier` is your app name

Comment: that is not making the trick unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Get the path to views.py from the `__file__` variable and use that to find the path to your CSV:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'files/t1.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```